# Chebyshev's theorem, is my answer correct to this question?

Tags: statistics, inequality

I was wondering if you guys could confirm if my answer is correct for this question regarding Chebyshev's theorem.

A random variable $X$ has a mean of $\mu=5$ and a variance $\sigma^2=36$ (i.e.: a standard deviation of $\sigma=6$). Using Chebyshev's theorem, find the value of the constant $c$ such that
$$P(|x-5|\geq c)\leq 0.75$$

My answer was $\displaystyle c = 6 \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}$.

Thought process: I first found the k value associated with a probability of .25 since this k value would tell me what range of data fall within 25% of the mean. After I obtained k, I just multiplied it by the standard deviation 6 and designated it as c since the probability of finding any random variable greater than c is going to be at max .75 since we are excluding all probabilities less than c. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LGTM.

Chebyshev says that $P(|X-5|/6\ge A)\le 1/A^2$, so $A^2=4/3$ and $c=6A$.